# Export follow condition laravel excel

Tags: laravel

I try to export some data using laravel excel.

But is this only have function export 1 table.

But I want to export a table with some condition mysql. For example I want to export user table to csv file but export with only student older than 20 years old. How can I do that? Thank very much.

Comment: You can use [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel). And in your export do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

For Excel export you can use [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/) package. Follow the documentation step by step to set it up.  For your conditions, in your controller you'd have to do something like this:

```
public function exportUsers() {
        $users = Users::where('years', '>', 20):
        return Excel::download( new UsersExport($users), 'users.xls');
    }
```